# Add Property Value in Message Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to add property value in message handler of asp.net webapi.
scenario is I implement webapi in which authenticationToken is part of different requests but client ask me to accept token in request header. but some applications are already using this api is sending token in request body.
so i don't want to change implementation. I want to read request header and if it contains header then assign that value to property of request.
is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to modify your request `uri` & `formdata` in message handler. Here is an example to do that, you can try this. I've added a `class APIKeyHandler` to handle this, and added handler in my `WebApiConfig`. I've uploaded a solution in my **Git** you can check it from [Example WebAPI with Modify Request Body in MessageHandler](https://github.com/csharpbd/Example-WebAPI-with-Modify-Request-Body-in-MessageHandler)

Code of `WebApiConfig`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //add the handler class in WebApiConfig
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new APIKeyHandler());
    }
}
```

Code of `APIKeyHandler`:

```
public class APIKeyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var formData = await request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();
        if (request.Method.Method.Equals("POST"))
        {
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(ModifyYourFormData(formData, request));
        }
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(ModifyYourURI(request.RequestUri.ToString(), request), UriKind.Absolute);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ModifyYourFormData(NameValueCollection source, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        //Add your logic here

        string Authorized = "";
        try
        {
            Authorized = request.Headers.GetValues("AuthorizedKey").FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> formData;
        formData = source.AllKeys.SelectMany(
            source.GetValues,
            (k, v) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k, v)).ToList();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Authorized))
        {
            formData.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AuthorizedKey", Authorized)); 
        }

        return formData;
    }

    public string ModifyYourURI(string uri, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        //Add your logic here

        string Authorized = "";
        try
        {
            Authorized = request.Headers.GetValues("AuthorizedKey").FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Authorized))
        {
            return uri + "?AuthorizedKey="+ Authorized;
        }
        else
        {
            return uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Code of `ExampleAPIController`:

```
public class ExampleAPIController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<string> Post()
    {
        string returnValue = "OK";

        var formKeyValueData = await Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();

        string AuthorizedKey = formKeyValueData["AuthorizedKey"];

        return returnValue;
    }

    public string Get(string AuthorizedKey)
    {
        string returnValue = "OK";
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

POST Request Calling Example:

[image]

GET Request Calling Example:

[image]

Comment: can I get request type and name of properties of request object in handler method?

Answer (score 0):

one more solution I figure out to add dynamic property in request

```
 if (request.Headers.Contains(HeaderName) && request.Method.Method.Equals("POST"))
            {
                var formData = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(formData);
                data.authenticationToken = request.Headers.GetValues(HeaderName).FirstOrDefault();
                request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            }
```